# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string, CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to get user_ID based on their name, and insert it into different table. Here's my controller:

```
    $customer = strtoupper($this->input->post('cust_name'));
    $address = $this->input->post('address');
    $category = $this->input->post('category');

    $sales = ($this->input->post('sic'));              
    $salesID = $this->user_model->getUserName($sales);       

    $result = $this->db->insert('customer', [        
        'cust_name' => $customer,
        'cust_address' => $address,
        'category' => $category,
        'user_id' => $salesID
    ]);
```

And my model:

```
public function getUserName($sales) {
    $this->db->select("user_id");
    $query = $this->db->get_where('user', ['name' => $sales]);
    return $query->row();
}
```

when I executed the query it always says "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

here the var_dump:

> object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["user_id"]=> string(2) "15" }

print_r:

> stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 15 )

how to solve this? thank you

Comment: try with remove `$this->db->select("user_id");` line

Comment: same stdClass error, here the print_r result `stdClass Object
(
    [user_id] => 15
    [name] => admin
    [password] => 47840d48c90990005b6f6c332f1b667319fb592d0461f0e67931b20210e595b1
    [email] => test@test.com
    [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [date_modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
)`

Comment: try this to get user_id  $salesID->user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hope this will help you :**

use `row` object like this :

```
  $salesID = $this->user_model->getUserName($sales);       

   $result = $this->db->insert('customer', [        
    'cust_name' => $customer,
    'cust_address' => $address,
    'category' => $category,
    'user_id' => $salesID->user_id  /* here is the change*/
  ]);
```

**Alternate way : return `user_id` like this :**

```
    public function getUserName($sales) {
       $this->db->select("user_id");
       $query = $this->db->get_where('user', ['name' => $sales]);
       return $query->row()->user_id;
    }
   /*then use it as you are using currently*/
```

Comment: whoa. I use the first one and it's working. new knowledge for me. thank you kind sir.

Comment: my pleasure, happy coding